# Java android BadTokenException on PopupWindow show

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

all search done and all that. many question about bad token exception on popupwindow. but nothing solved this issue. first of all, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work. which makes things way more complicated.

code:

```
private void PopupWindowManagement(PopupWindow popup, boolean dismiss, boolean show, View view, int resource, int gravity, int OFFSET_X, int OFFSET_Y) {
    int i;
    boolean reinitialize = false;
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contextPublic);
    String shiftID = settings.getString("shift_id", "");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            if (reinitialize) {
                contextPublic = AantarnetClientActivity.this;
                sendEmail("popup " + (show ? "show" : "dismiss") + " reinit 1 resource=" + resource + " i=" + i + " shift_id=" + shiftID + " plateNbr=" + plateNbr);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contextPublic.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, new LinearLayout(contextPublic), false);
                popup.setContentView(view);
                sendEmail("popup " + (show ? "show" : "dismiss") + " reinit 2 resource=" + resource + " i=" + i + " shift_id=" + shiftID + " plateNbr=" + plateNbr);
            }
            if (show) {
                if (popup != null && !popup.isShowing()) {
                    popup.showAtLocation(view, gravity, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);
                }
            } else if (dismiss) {
                if (popup != null && popup.isShowing()) {
                    popup.dismiss();
                }
            }
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sendEmail("popup " + (show ? "show" : "dismiss") + " resource=" + resource + " i=" + i + " shift_id=" + shiftID + " plateNbr=" + plateNbr);
            reinitialize = true;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                sendEmail("popup " + (show ? "show" : "dismiss") + " sleep resource=" + resource + " i=" + i + " shift_id=" + shiftID + " plateNbr=" + plateNbr);
                //e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log("hanna: DismissDialog=" + i);
        }
    }
    if(i == 5) {
        sendEmail("popup " + (show?"show":"dismiss") + " shift_id=" + shiftID + " plateNbr=" + plateNbr);
    }
}
```

so the for loop is to try 5 times if the first one fails, apparently, this code is happening once and the popup is not showing SOMETIMES. some other times it simply works and shows the popup.

as you see i made a function to send an email in different conditions, here are some emails. (if there was no exceptions nothing happens, no email sent)

email in case of exception:

email1:

```
version 1.8 message popup show resource=2130903048 i=0 shift_id=7471 plateNbr=380998
```

email2:

```
version 1.8 message popup show reinit 1 resource=2130903048 i=1 shift_id=7471 plateNbr=380998
```

sometimes i get email3:

```
version 1.8 message popup show reinit 2 resource=2130903048 i=1 shift_id=7471 plateNbr=380998
```

as you can see i is now equal 1, means it entered into the if (reinitialize), but never reached the end of it, and no other exceptions seen since no other emails were sent, it simply does not show the popup. but i cannot reinitialize the whole popup due the many reasons i cannot say

any help or questions or further info, please let me know.

Comment: Try and check if you have a static variable of the same which makes it out-live the activity it is attached to

Comment: static variable of what? only the contextPublic is static. but i saw it in my own eyes, that same activity was showing, two times popup showed but the next didn't